# JURI::root() does not return the live site param

Tags: joomla

In joomla 2.5 the JURI::root() does not return the http://www.example.com/ but the local ip of the server where the site is hosted ex.: `http://192.168.10.10/`
Is there a way to give JURI::root() a fixed string?
The web server is behind ISA
Thanks

Comment: Whatbdo you have defined for the $live_site variable in the configuration.php ?

Comment: public $live_site = 'http://www.example.com/'

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below thread, similar question has been solved here.

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=231&t=301738

http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/root